# Regex expression to parse $ and ¢ currency values

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to parse out currency values that are using both $ and ¢ formats. For instance, I'll have values like "$0.50" and "50¢".
I would ideally like an expression that would return .50 or 0.50 for both of those values.

Working with the below expression works fine for $ formatted values, but "50¢" would return as 50 (which I then interpret as 50 dollars).

```
([0-9,.]+)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: search for the cent symbol before using your expression. You can use it to parse appropriately.

Comment: What about `\$((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)?\.\d{2})|(\d{2})¢`?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off doing your operation in two steps. In the first step, you can run the following regex:

```
\$\d+\.?,?\d+
```

This will return all the $ values, which you can interpret as is. You can then run the following:

```
\d+¢
```

Which will return all the cents, which you can then divide by 100 to get your desired result.

Either way, use this [fantastic regex testing tool](https://regex101.com/) all the time.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to combine these 2 steps as a conditional in Regex?

Comment: @Ryan The problem isn't the regex per se, it's the replace for the cents part. Conditional replacement is possible with regex, but the final solution will be far more complex than what we have here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
r = /(\$?)([0-9,.]+)(¢?)/
```

Then the returning object will contain the following info (called with: `r.exec('$0.50')`):

```
0:"$0.50"
1:"$"
2:"0.50"
3:""
```

So, after executing the regex, you can extract the value with `2` and then check for `1` to see if dollars, otherwise, check `3` to see that it's cents.

Answer (score 0):

I think this work perfectly the reg `[$¢]` will replace any caracter between the double bracket and for `50¢` just append `0.`

```js
 a = "$0.50"  
 b = "0.50¢"
 c = "0.50$" 
 d = "¢0.50"
 e = "50¢"
 
 
console.log(a.replace(/[$¢]/,""))
console.log(b.replace(/[$¢]/,""))
console.log(c.replace(/[$¢]/,""))
console.log(d.replace(/[$¢]/,""))
console.log("0." + e.replace(/[$¢]/,""))
```

Comment: Did you test this for `50¢`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes you can check in the console log , `b = "0.50¢"`

Comment: If I test `console.log("50¢".replace(/[$¢]/,""));` I get `50`. The OP would like this to be `0.50`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Ah yes you're , i will edit my answear

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure to prepend a leading '.' (if not present) to cents operations.

```
 "50¢".replace(/(^[0-9]*¢$)/, ".$1")
```

.50¢

```
"0.50¢".replace(/(^[0-9]*¢$)/, ".$1")
```

0.50¢

```
"$50".replace(/(^[0-9]*¢$)/, ".$1")
```

$50

Answer (score 0):

`getCash` turns the money string into a returnable object that has the properties `dollars`, `cents`, and the method `format`

```js
let a = "$0.50",
  b = "50¢", 
  c = "$5.65",
  d = "3.33";


function getCash(cash) {
  let RemoveMoneyChars = (str) => str.replace(/\D/gmi, "");

  obj = {
    cents: 0,
    dollars: 0,
    format: function() {
    if(this.dollars && this.cents) {
    return `$${this.dollars}.${this.cents}`;
    }
    else if(this.dollars && !this.cents) {
    return `$${this.dollars}`;
    }
    else if(!this.dollars && this.cents) {
    return `.${this.cents}`;
    }
    }
 };

  if (cash.includes(".")) {
    let dc = cash.split(".");
    let dollars = dc[0], cents = dc[1];

    dollars = RemoveMoneyChars(dollars);
    cents = RemoveMoneyChars(cents);
    obj.cents = parseInt(cents);
    obj.dollars = parseInt(dollars);
  }
  else {
    if (cash.slice(-1) === "¢") {
      obj.cents = parseInt(RemoveMoneyChars(cash));
    } else {
      obj.dollars = parseInt(RemoveMoneyChars(cash));
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

let money = getCash(a), money2 = getCash(b), money3 = getCash(c), money4 = getCash(d);
console.log(a, b, c, d);
console.log(".format()", money.format(), money2.format(), money3.format(), money4.format());
console.log(".dollars", money.dollars, money2.dollars, money3.dollars, money4.dollars);
console.log(".cents", money.cents, money2.cents, money3.cents, money4.cents);
```